# When an addict can't get access to the drugs he needs, he feels/is ....?

Tags: word-request

When a habitual drunkard or an opium addict consumes his alcohol or let's say opium, he becomes drunk or stoned. If not, he starts acting moody or strange, smashing things, feeling pain in his body, or simply being too lethargic.

In other words, if the least amount of a narcotic in a person's blood, based on the habit that he himself developed, is 3 mg, using 4 miligram makes him stoned/drunk and dropping the level of narcotic to 2 mg makes him **[the word]**.

Both formal and informal ways to describe this state are welcome.

**Note** (for Persian speakers): The word I'm looking for is خمار.

**Edit**: Based on the answers given so far I get the impression that there is probably not a single specific word with this description. So I include a continuum here that may be helpful.

[ word ] ------> sober -------> intoxicated

Definition: the state of being a drug user who didn't get his drugs on time, esp. when it refers to being lethargic.

Comment: +1 for all. I suppose there is no a specific or technical term in English to fit in the continuum although there is one in Persian, so I simply need to describe that with other words describing the mood without necessarily having anything to do with drugs. Thank you.

Comment: `[ word ] ------> sober -------> intoxicated` makes no sense to me as a spectrum.  Are you looking for **sedated**?  ?

Comment: @TRomano I made that up :) you see on the right side we have _under the influence of **drugs**_ (intoxicated), and on the left side we have _under the influence of **no drugs** having consumed for an addict_ [the word].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The repeated use of alcohol or drugs can lead to [dependence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substance_dependence) on it. When one stops consuming the drug, one can experience **withdrawal symptoms** or **[withdrawal syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Withdrawal_syndrome)**. (See also [drug withdrawal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drug_withdrawal).)

After consuming too much alcohol (not necessarily repeatedly), one can also experience a **[hangover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangover)**. (The English Wikipedia article about hangover links to the article [خماری](https://fa.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%AE%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%B1%DB%8C) in the Persian version of Wikipedia. The Persian Wiktionary article [خمار](https://fa.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D8%AE%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%B1) mentions *hung over* and *languid* as related words.) The word you are looking for at the end of your example sentence may be **languid**.

Answer (score 2):

Informally, if an addict can't get the drugs he wants, he's [**jonesing**](http://mentalfloss.com/article/49625/how-did-jones-come-mean-craving) for them, or he's **got a jones** for them.  (*Jones* and *jonesing* are sometimes used just to mean "craving something" now, by extension.)

For example,

> Mitch and Mark set out to find a fresh smack connection.  They hit Jackson Street and there is no problem finding the drugs that by now they both crave.  They aren't sick, just jonesing for a fix.

(Source: [*A Place for Me: International Street Life to Spiritual Insight*, by Colby Chase](https://books.google.com/books?id=wcc7G5z2hm4C&pg=PA336&dq=%22jonesing%20for%20a%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjy6tmBqqDPAhVp9YMKHVS4B3AQ6AEIITAB#v=onepage&q=%22jonesing%20for%20a%22&f=false))

Answer (score 0):

Withdrawal makes the addict initially **irritable**, i.e. overly sensitive to stimuli, quick to be angered or set off.

Comment: I upvoted you because your word can be used in this sense although it doesn't imply lethargy at all. On the other hand, I understand there is probably no English word to fit the continuum so I can't expect an English speaker to target it.

Comment: @Yuri:  I understood you to be asking for a word that means the opposite of "lethargy". " ... he starts acting moody or strange, smashing things..."

Comment: You're right but all these can be the after effects of this state and as I mentioned in OP "...feeling pain in his body, **or** simply being too lethargic." Some might even fall asleep suddenly. Here we simly use an adjective in Persian which can mean all these. A word which kind of means _under the influence of no drugs_!! Ofcourse to describe a habitual drug user :) The words _irritable, languid, sleepy, lethargic, etc_ don't imply the notion of drug using.

Comment: Your question was unclear. It seemed you were asking for a word that described a habitual drug user who was going through withdrawal.  All three of the answers understood the question to be just that, mine, stangdon's, and Christophe's.

Comment: I know and that's why I upvoted all the answers. As I said if you want to make the meaning of the Persian word in English you need a clause as you yourself put it: the state of "a habitual drug user who was going through withdrawal." I don't think there is any entry in an English dictionary with such a definition but there is one in Persian.

Comment: The state of a drug user going through opiate withdrawal can vary: agitated, irritated, anxious, scattered, listless.  You're saying there's a single word in Persian which encompasses all of those states? Or does the word simply mean "undergoing opiate withdrawal"?

Comment: I don't think neither of your options negates the other. When an addict is anxious, scattered, listless, generally weird and you can notice it then you can say he's undergoing opiate withdrawl otherwise you can't really say that! In persian if you see an addict very anxious you can say he's probably [the word]. The single word denotes that person is acting like this (anxious, aggressive, sleepy, etc)because he's undergoing a withdrawal. Anyway if there is also a word meaning _undergoing withdrawal_ I think that will do. I guess I can use a phrase like you suggested _undergoing withdrawal_.